# rewriting equation in terms of $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From Stewart, Precalculus, 5th ed, P98, Q.45

$$x^2+xy+y^2=4$$

how can I re-write this equation in terms of $y$? I want to put this equation into graphing software but don't know to put $y$ on one side and $x$ on the other.

Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of $x$ (or $y$) as a constant, then you get something of the form:
$$ay^2 + by + c = 0.$$
The solution to this $2$. degree equation will give you $y$ as a function of $x$. You will get two solutions (plus/minus square root) which can both be plotted.

More specifically you will get:
$$y^2 + xy + x^2 - 4 = 0$$

Solution is then:
$$y = -\frac{x}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 4x^2 + 16}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+xy+y^2=4$

$\displaystyle x^2+2(x)(\frac y 2)+(\frac y 2)^2+\frac {3y^2} 4=4$

$\displaystyle (x+\frac y 2)^2 = 4-\frac {3y^2} 4$

$\displaystyle x+\frac y 2 = \pm \frac{\sqrt{16-3y^2}}2$

$\displaystyle x= \frac{-y\pm\sqrt{16-3y^2}}2$

This is a method known as completing square.

Answer (score 1):

rewrite in quadratic form in x
$$x^2+xy+(y^2-4)=0$$
any quadratic equation $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ has a two roots
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
 so that
$$x=\frac{-y\pm\sqrt {16-3y^2}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is a quadratic equation in $x$. So, use the standard quadratic solution.